# python pandas - group by date and count

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe. Date in DD/MM/YY

```
Date                        id     
1/5/2017 2:00 PM            100
1/5/2017 3:00 PM            101
2/5/2017 10:00 AM           102
3/5/2017  09:00 AM          103
3/5/2017  10:00 AM          104
4/5/2017  09:00 AM          105
```

Need output such a way that , able to group by date and also count number of Ids per day  , also ignore time. o/p new data frame should be as below

```
DATE           Count
1/5/2017        2           -> count 100,101
2/5/2017        1
3/5/2017        2
4/5/2017        1
```

Need efficient way to achieve above.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df['Date'].dt.date.value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['DATE','Count']
```

Alternative solution:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date).size().reset_index(name='Count')

print (df1)
         DATE  Count
0  2017-05-01      2
1  2017-05-02      1
2  2017-05-03      2
3  2017-05-04      1
```

If need same format:

```
df1 = df['Date'].str.split().str[0].value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['DATE','Count']
```

---

```
new = df['Date'].str.split().str[0]
df1 = df.groupby(new).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
       Date  Count
0  1/5/2017      2
1  2/5/2017      1
2  3/5/2017      2
3  4/5/2017      1
```

Comment: Thank you. One issue is o/p is not sorted by date. df1.sort_values(by=['DATE']) not helping.

Comment: @user10319580 I think better is convert date column to datetimes like in first solution, then sorting work nice.